# Display posts belonging to category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to get the posts that belong to each category, i had this working before but i can't seem to find what i have done wrong here.

I have a Post Table and a Categories Table

ROUTE

```
Route::get('articles/category/{id}', ['as' => 'post.category', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@getPostCategory']);
```

CONTROLLER

```php
public function getPostCategory($id)
{
    $postCategories = PostCategory::with('posts')
        ->where('post_category_id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

    $categories = PostCategory::all();

    // return view
    return view('categories.categoriesposts')->with('postCategories', $postCategories)->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

VIEW

```
@foreach($postCategories->posts as $post)

    <div class="well">

        <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
            </a>

            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">{{ substr($post->title, 0, 50) }}</h4>
                <p class="text-right">By Francisco</p>
                <p>{{ substr($post->body, 0, 90) }}</p>
                <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

POST MODAL

```
public function postCategory()
{   
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PostCategory');
}
```

POSTCATEGORY MODAL

```
class PostCategory extends Model
{
    // connect Categories to Posts tables
    protected $table = 'post_categories';

    // Category belongs to more than 1 post
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'post_category_id');
    }
}
```

I can't see what i am doing wrong every time I go to a category it shows

> Trying to get property of non-object

Any help will be much appreciated thanks

Comment: maybe this category don't have any posts ? use whereHas('posts') before with('posts')

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: No this isnt the issue i think i have a bug somewhere else which is throwing the error. Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/macpro/sites/sixmedia/resources/views/pages/frontend/articles/single.blade.php)

Comment: Could you please `dd($post);` in your blade file so that we can see if you are managing to call in the post successfully?

Comment: I don't know why it is throwing this error because i am not trying to access the getSingle function

Comment: The thing is with `non-object` it means, there is no `post` who got this attribute. So therefore there is no `post` in this `category` or the backend isnt receiving any `posts` from the query.

Comment: The post relationship is working fine because i can call $post->postCategory in my blade and it works. I have several posts in each category so this is not the issue either

Comment: I think the bug is elsewhere because it was working before, and the error i am getting is related to the getSingle function which works totally fine so i am very confused

Comment: Try to call the `posts` method of one category in artisan tinker.

Comment: Its definitely a bug because when i try to do the same thing on another controller it works.. What is the best way to debug

Answer (score 0):

replace your lines:

```
$postCategories = PostCategory::with('posts')       
             ->where('post_category_id', '=', $id)
             ->first();
```

with:

```
    $postCategories = PostCategory::find($id)->posts;
```

Change your line in your PostCategoryModel to:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'post_category_id','post_category_id');
```